# Conveniently switch between Apple and PC keyboard (swap Windows and Alt keys)

Tags: keyboard, automation

I alternate between a Unicomp [clicky keyboard](http://pckeyboards.stores.yahoo.net/en104bl.html) by day, and the Apple bluetooth keyboard by night.

The Apple keyboard physically swaps the <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Windows</kbd> keys. How do I counteract this?

Also, how can I streamline the process since I switch keyboards twice per day.

Answer (score 6):

This is on Ubuntu 10.04.

### Manually swapping the Windows and Alt keys

1. System -> Preferences -> Keyboard
2. Layouts tab
3. Click "Options..."
4. Expand "Alt/Win key behavior"
5. Choose between:

   - Default (when using the PC keyboard)
   - "LeftAlt is swapped with Left Win" (when using the Apple keyboard)

### Semi-automated swapping

I have added this to my `.bashrc`:

```
# Output the gconf settings for enabled or disabled keyboard swapping based on whether the argument is "apple"
setting_for_alt_key () {
  gconftool --get /desktop/gnome/peripherals/keyboard/kbd/options \
  | ruby -e 'set = {}; STDIN.gets.strip.gsub(/\]|\[/, "").split(",").each{|x| set[x]=1}; set["altwin\taltwin:swap_lalt_lwin"]=1; STDOUT.write "[" + set.keys.select{|x| ARGV[0] == "apple" || x !~ /swap_lalt/ }.join(",") + "]"' \
    "$1"
}

kmac () { gconftool --set --type=list --list-type=string /desktop/gnome/peripherals/keyboard/kbd/options "$(setting_for_alt_key apple)"; }
kpc  () { gconftool --set --type=list --list-type=string /desktop/gnome/peripherals/keyboard/kbd/options "$(setting_for_alt_key)"; }
```

Then when I activate the Apple keyboard, I type `kmac` at the terminal. When I deactivate it, I type `kpc`. So far I have not been able to justify auto-detection.

(Also, if somebody has a better way to work with Gconf, either with `gconftool-2` or perhaps language bindings, I'd love to hear it.)

Answer (score 0):

Go to System>Preferences>Keyboard and add the appropriate keyboard layouts you want to use. Then in the layouts tab click the "Options..." button and find "Keys to change layout" and find a keyboard short cut that you will like.

Comment: To my knowledge, the keyboard layout is unrelated to my question of swapping the keys. Would you please confirm your technique and follow up? Thanks.

Comment: There are layouts for mac keyboards, and I cant really confirm since I haven't got a mac keyboard.